# Select statement in SQLite does not return result

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Then the following must return the password of the user stored in the DB

```
public String getPasswordByUsername(String userName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
            + KEY_USERS_USERNAME + " = " + userName;

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
```

When I try to get the password of the user "w", I get:

```
12-24 10:54:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(11237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 10:54:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(11237): Process: com.example.doit, PID: 11237
12-24 10:54:23.639: E/AndroidRuntime(11237): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: w (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  password FROM users WHERE username = w
```

Here is what is stored in DB:
[image]

How can I fetch the right password? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `" = " + userName` to : `" = '" + username+ "'"`

Comment: `username` will not be properly escaped if it contains a `'` and crash

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) example this done in the way I did this, and it worked fine. Why is it  so?

Comment: It is done like this " = " + todo_id where todo_id is type of Long and " = '" + tag_name + "'" where tag_name is type of String.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this: (include quotes)

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
        + KEY_USERS_USERNAME + " = '" + userName + "'";
```

At the moment you are creating an SQL string with no quotes, so it is not treated as a string, and instead is treating it as a column name. which does not exist.

Comment: `username` will not be properly escaped if it contains a `'` and crash

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/) example this done in the way I did this, and it worked fine. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to pass `username` into the `selectionArgs` in `rawQuery`'s 2nd param/arg, example:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE "
        + KEY_USERS_USERNAME + " =  ?";

Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{ username });
```

This way if your `username` value is `w` or even `"w'` it will be properly escaped in your resulting sql statement that is executed.

Answer (score 1):

change to this simple formate:-

*String dateQuery = "SELECT * FROM user where username='" + USERNAME+"'";*

Cursor data = db.rawQuery(dateQuery, null);

i think its helpfull .